# Script to change Small RX Buffers in the Advanced Properties of the NIC

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cluster-computing, vmware, nic

We are experiencing packet loss on our SQL 2012 Always On Windows Clusters running in our virtual environment.
Through our troubleshooting we have found that we need to increase the Small RX buffers on our SQL 2012 Always On Clusters from the default of 1024 to 8192. (reference link below)

I can do this in the GUI all day, but there are several 2012 Always On setups running in our environment where this setting needs to be changed.

I've followed the reference below and I'm not finding the setting changes reflected in the registry (even after reboot) so I can reference the key to change.

Note: I am running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Clustering (wishing I was on Windows Server 2012 with the new PowerShell Commands).

I'm looking for the right place to update this setting, the method can be just about anything other than clicking through the GUI (I have the Steps for the GUI in the Reference below).

Is there a way I can update the Small Rx Buffers via script on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Reference: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2039495

Comment: Most likely you could use netsh.exe to change the setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any better answers you could use WASP (on codeplex) to automate interacting with the GUI. WASP makes writing scripts to do that kind of interaction pretty easy.